# Creating dynamic hyperlink in asp.net using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my application I have DataSet containing name and Id of user and I want to create a dynamic hyperlink of the all the user name. Please anyone tell me how to create dynamic hyperlink using C#.

Answer (score 2):

As @Ashley John said,

```
        HyperLink DynLink = new HyperLink();
        DynLink.ID = "DynLink";
        DynLink.Text = "This Link Is been Created Dynamically from code behind";
        DynLink.NavigateUrl = "~/TestPage.aspx";

        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(DynLink);
```

I have used a placeholder as a container to hold the dynamically generated Hyperlink..

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a new instance of Hyperlink Control
2. Set its URL property.
3. Add the Control to the placeholder(or Gridview controls collection if you are using it inside a Gridview) where you want it to get displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Asp.Net HyperLink control. You can create the url passed to the Hyperlink control by using String.Format().

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a list of all hyperlinks you could have a look at the Repeater and use Eval("...") in the template to render out the link. That way, you can define more in markup then in code.

Answer (score 0):

We can create Dynamic Hyperlink using following Syntax:

```
<asp:DynamicHyperlink
    ID="string"
    Action="Details|Edit|Insert|List"
    ContextTypeName="string"
    DataField="string"
    TableName="string"
    OnDataBinding="DataBinding event handler"
    OnPreRender="PreRender event handler"/>
```

For more detail just go to [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.dynamicdata.dynamichyperlink.aspx). You will get a Demo Project Showing use of Dynamic Hyperlink and Linq.